# Ember.js How to show the dynamic segment in the view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my routes, I have this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', function() {
        this.route('search', {path: 'search/:query'});
    });
});
```

And in my search route, I have this:

```
App.PostsSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return Em.$.getJSON('posts?q=' + params.query);
    }
});
```

So when I go to the url: `/posts/search/posttobesearched`, `params.query` becomes `posttobesearched`.

Now, in my search template, I would like `posttobesearched` to be shown. I did it like this:

```
<h2>Search Results for: <em>{{query}}</h2>
```

But it didn't show the `query`.

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your controller needs to have this on it:

```
  queryParams: ['query'],
  query: null
```

and then I think that your {{query}} in a template should work at that point.

[ edit ] Also, note that you have to have the query params feature on: query-params-new. You can read more about this in http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/ which I'm guessing you probably have already read.

Note also that I think what you **probably** want is actually for the query param to be q, given that's what you have in your API. You really should re-read the linked piece and follow that.